# Footer HTML not attached to bottom

Tags: html, css

It's a little bit strange.
In my 2 HTML pages i have a footer that is equal to both but in one, that is shorter than the other, the footer goes up and leave a space at the bottom of like 30px.
(In the longer page the footer stay attached to the bottom)

Here is the css of the footer and the body:

```
footer{
    background-color: #0b2239;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

html, body{
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

I've tried to resolve it by adding `bottom: 0;` but in the longer page the footer go over the other element in the page

Comment: tried `bottom: 0px` on footer element?

Comment: it doesn't work the footer in the longer page go over other element

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add to the `footer` the value `bottom: 0;`

```
footer{
    background-color: #0b2239;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
}

html, body{
    min-height: 100%;
}
```